# Loop through each image in a table, performing an animation on each

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wish to know how I would go about looping through all images in a table and performing an animation on each one.

I know this may require pulling each image into an array, and then looping through getting the image at the current position and applying the animation; but I am not sure how to do this.

I don't mind if the solution is using Jquery or javascript.

My table is as follows:

```
<table id="prevWorkTable">
        <tr>
            <td><img id="twitt" src="images/prev_work_back.png" /></td>
            <td><img src="images/prev_work_back.png" /></td>
            <td><img src="images/prev_work_back.png" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

And the animation I wish to apply is this:

```
 var right = $('#twitt');
  right.show("fast");
  var width =  parseInt(100 * right.width() /right.parent().width() + 10,10);
  $('#twitt').animate({
      "width": "-="+ width 
  }, "slow");
```

So in regards to the above animation the variable 'right' would hold the current image and so would the variable 'twitt'.

Please do not feel like you have to write tons of code, just a link to a similar solution would be fine.

Thanks in advance!

Callum

Comment: I would look into doing this with css animations rather than js, you could trigger them by adding a class to the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do differently.

Create CSS animation (keyframe) for a class called "animate_me".

```
@keyframes example {
    from {background-color: red;}
    to {background-color: yellow;}
}

/* The element to apply the animation to */
.animate_me {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 4s;
}
```

Add this class to the elements you want to animate.

```
$("table#prevWorkTable img").each(function(){
     var right = $(this);
     right.addClass("animate_me");
});
```

Lighter and faster.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! Ok this seems like an interesting and new approach, just one question. How would I add jquery animation to this then? Because in the above example you have shown using CSS animation, however I will need to perform an animation that requires jquery libraries if that makes sense

Comment: @CallumHolden you dont use JQuery animation in such a way. You use CSS animations. You can do same animations wit CSS, just with some creativity. And even very amazing ones ! In my example, when you addClass, the CSS animation (for this class) fires automatically. addClass = play the CSS animation for this class "animate_me".I edit my question with the same animation as yours.

Comment: Ok I understand. Your JQ animation is progressive, with CSS you are more static. I dont know if you can edit CSS `keyframe` with JQ.

Comment: Hi, to be honest what you have given me above is pretty efficient and is very clean and quick. I might change the animation to suit the above approach because it is better than having large javascript code running in the background. Thanks for this, it has helped me a lot! +1

Comment: @CallumHolden Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another Answer without CSS:

```
$("table#prevWorkTable > tr > td").each(function(){
     var right = $(this).find( "img" ); // <=== here, take IMG from TD
     right.show("fast");
     var width =  parseInt(100 * right.width() /right.parent().width() + 10,10);
     right.animate({
         "width": "-="+ width 
     }, "slow");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

using Jquery and selecting *img* under the *table*

```
$("table#prevWorkTable img").each(function(){
     var right = $(this);
     right.show("fast");
     var width =  parseInt(100 * right.width() /right.parent().width() + 10,10);
     right.animate({
         "width": "-="+ width 
     }, "slow");
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! This does not seem to be working. When I try and interrogate the SRC value of each image in the loop, it is returning 'Undefined' which makes me to believe that it is not getting each object correctly possibly?

Comment: `$("table#prevWorkTable img").each(function(){` cannot work. I post a new answer.

Comment: using $(this).attr("src") u can get src